# Blogpost vs. blog post

Tags: orthography, writing-style, compounds, spacing

Have I written a **blogpost** or a **blog post**?

I've seen both forms used but am not sure which is the "correct" one, if there's any.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blogpost and http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blog-post

Answer (score 4):

When two words are frequently used together people might start to hyphenate them, and then some time later they might start to concatenate them.

It's a question of you having a feel for the usage and seeing which you are most comfortable using and with what audience, e.g. 'blogpost' with Tumbloggers and 'blog post' with your parents. But maybe that's your question? I prefer 'blog post', but then again I'm still getting used to 'miniseries'.